# How would I get an ID from a response like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is the response in question:

```
Object { 0: <li#gen_kw_select_77080.actions-list__option.j-selected.j-focused>, context: <li#gen_kw_select_77080.actions-list__option.j-selected.j-focused>, length: 1 }
```

And here is the code that generates it:

```
function doAction (items) {
    items.each(function(index, el) {
      var $el = $(el);
      console.log($el);
      $el.addClass('animate');

      setTimeout(function() {
        $el.removeClass('animate');
      }, 300);
    });
  }
```

I highly appreciate any responses here. I should probably mention that I'm using the selectonic plugin.

Comment: do you mean $el.attr('id') ?

Comment: Or more simply `el.id`, if `el` is an element as the name would suggest.

Comment: You have the reference to the element so read the attribute?

Comment: Amadan, that's why I've posted here. Doing that did not work surprisingly. And thanks @EricSo.

Comment: Not enough code shown then if `el.id` doesn't do it. Need to provide enough code for us to reproduce this ....and a demo would be really helpful